Set Asset Path for .webc files in Eleventy
In a .webc file, I have something like this
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>

and when running eleventy build, the file path is considered as src/_components/js/common.js. Is it possible to change any configuration so that it will look for the file in static/js/ instead ?
